# How much of the manga did the Sankarea anime cover?

Tags: sankarea

I just recently finished Sankarea anime and want to start the manga. How much of the manga did it cover?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anime seemed to jump around a bit, especially the 12th episode of the anime.

However, till the 11th episode, the **anime mainly covers the manga till Chapter 9**, so you might want to start reading from Chapter 10.

Answer (score 0):

The anime and the manga are almost like two different stories, content-wise.

The main plot is the "same" (so much of the story doesn't exist in the anime version, thus it's the same regarding the direction that the story is heading in, but the path is just a fraction of the original, manga's path), but in the manga, the story is finished.

The anime covers about 30% of what there is to the story (so if it wasn't already made obvious, know what little of the story the anime does cover, it's somewhat changed as compared to the manga).

The anime completely omits a large amount of things. One of the things that the anime omits is the main character. The main character, Darin-chan, is completely omitted from the anime version of the story (thoughts of dropping the anime at that point when I had realised that were quenched by my will/intent to finish what I start).

As the other answer says, the anime covers up 'till chapter 9 of the manga, and there are 56 chapters to it. I mean, the anime is logically basically a promotion for the manga, rather than a standalone thing (I don't think this is true, but it could be).

In conclusion, my opinion is that you shouldn't consider yourself as having experienced the story by just having seen the anime. The manga is the story, the anime is just... something less, with beautiful music. And the anime helped me personally to value the story more. In the manga, it was all a bunch of tropes (cliches) one after another. The anime helped me consider the story a lot more sincerely, the aspects of it that were present in and presented with the anime.